# How to force collapse all expansion panels?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want to force close my expansion panel when I clicked **Update**

[image]

How do I programmatically do that ?

This is what I have in my update().

```
update(index) {
  console.log("index", index);

  let vehicle = {};
  vehicle.VIN = this.savedVehicles[index].VIN;
  vehicle.ModelYear = this.savedVehicles[index].ModelYear;
  vehicle.Make = this.savedVehicles[index].Make;
  vehicle.Model = this.savedVehicles[index].Model;

  this.savedVehicles[index] = vehicle;
  localStorage.setItem("savedVehicles", JSON.stringify(this.savedVehicles));

  this.alert = true;
  this.alertColor = "green";
  this.alertMessage = `${vehicle.VIN} updated`;

  // hope to collapse all expansion panels 

},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Expansion panels can be controlled externally by modifying the
> v-model. Its value corresponds to a zero-based index of the currently
> opened expansion panel content. If multiple props are used then it is an
> array containing the indices of the open items.

1. To control the opening and closing status of multiple panels
   https://codepen.io/pen?&editors=101
2. If need to control only a single expansion panel then use this-

```
<template>
  <v-expansion-panels v-model="panel">
     // any code here
  </v-expansion-panels>
  <button @click="closePanel()">Close</button>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      panel: 0 // This means should open by default
    }
  },
  methods: {
    closePanel() {
      this.panel = null; // null is to close the panel
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me.

I have multiple panels and each panel is a component

Comment: Did you check the code sandbox link I provided to control multiple panels?